# How to use Multitenant in Nhibernate with Spring in MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nhibernate, multi-tenant

I have an application in MVC with Hnibernate deployed on a server. Currently only one client is using this application. Now there are many clients and all will use this app with different database but the schema will same for all.
For this implementation I am thinking an approach-
I have made a new database in which table hold the information regarding the individual Client database connection strings.
When the application run, Nhiberate makes multiple session factories for all database which includes all client databases and the main database.
For example- there are two clients 'A' and 'B' with their database name 'A_db' and 'B_db'. And the other main database which hold connection strings as 'All_db'. Then in this case nhibernate make 3 session factories for all three db.
So when user enter their login credential, i'll check the related connection string for that client from the main database. and then destroy all session factories which are not related to that client database connection string. So by doing this there will be only one session factory remain that belong to his database. 
Is this my approach is correct??
And i am going in right direction then provide some code for this approach as making multiple session factories and after then removing all session factories except the related one?

Comment: Why separate database per client when you can simply add Client_Id column in respective tables in one and single database?

Comment: Thats an application as well as client need for the separate database.

Comment: @AmitJoshi that's a bad idea. One mistake in your query and clients can see each others data.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a connectionstring to the GetSession method. Check out this [link](https://patrickhuber.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/change-connectionstring-nhibernate/) for more intel.